# Can I declare a function pointer inside a function?

Tags: c#, function-pointers

I'm confused with the C# ways of declaring function pointers. I'd like to declare **one-line** a function pointer variable inside a function, without having to add class members or stuff like that.

What I'm trying is:

```
System.Func<KeyCode, bool> inputCheck = activeCharacter.continuous_fire ? Input.GetKey : Input.GetKeyDown;
```

I've tried to also use `Action` (but apparently it doesn't return a value) and `delegate`, but apparently I got it wrong.

Can I do this somehow (i.e. I'm just getting the syntax wrong), or the only way to do that is by first declaring a `delegate` prototype?

**edit**: to clarify, currently I have to do this:

```
    bool do_fire=false;
    if (activeCharacter.continuous_fire)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey( Fire ))
        {
            do_fire=true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown( Fire ))
        {
            do_fire=true;
        }
    }
```

Since this looks awful **and redundant** (and redundant is almost always wrong), I'd like to just put the Input.* function in a variable and check that.

pseudo-code:

```
    bool do_fire=false;
    function keyCheck = activeCharacter.continuous_fire ? Input.GetKey : Input.GetKeyDown;
    if (keyCheck( Fire ))
    {
        do_fire=true;
    }
```

Comment: Delegates are different from plain function pointers. They point to both an instance and a function.

Comment: You can use the lambda syntax: `Func<KeyCode, bool> inputCheck = (keyCode)=> ...`

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: Assuming both GetKey and GetKeyDown are static methods and take a KeyCode as an argument and return a bool, and that continues_fire returns a boolean, that statement is perfectly legal.

Comment: @dcastro I get `Assets/Sources/Characters.cs(55,44): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'method group' to 'System.Func<UnityEngine.KeyCode,bool>'`

Comment: That's weird... Try explicitly casting the left side operand to a func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works in principle, the conditional operator is just unable to determine the common type between “method group” and “method group”. The reason for this is that the methods *could* be overloaded (even though they’re not in your case), and hence can have more than one signature.

You resolve this by casting either of the arguments explicitly to the target delegate type:

```
Func<KeyCode, bool> checkFire = activeCharacter.continuous_fire ?
        (Func<KeyCode, bool>)Input.GetKey : Input.GetKeyDown;
```

Furthermore, your test code is needlessly complex, even after you’ve introduced your `inputCheck`. There’s no need for any `if`. Assign `do_fire` directly instead:

```
bool do_fire = checkFire(Fire);
```

An additional remark: your coding conventions are a chaotic mix, you should clean this up. C# generally uses `PascalCase` for public-facing identifiers and all types, and `camelCase` for the rest. `snake_case` is never used.

In other words, it should be:

- `activeCharacter.ContinuousFire`
- `doFire`
- `fire`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! About the second issue you point out, that's because I might have added more stuff inside there, other than just the `do_fire` assignation. Thanks for pointing out the messy conventions too! : )